# Prevent .click function jumping to top of the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle, page-jump

Im using the below code to simulate a .animate toggle effect. However, when clicking the page will jump to the top. I've tried using prevent but it still jumps so I think I'm missing something... Any ideas?

```
$(function() {
$('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {// odd clicks 

    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-bars fa-times');
    $(this).toggleClass('cross');
    $('.menu-over ul li').toggleClass('animated-fast slideInLeft')

    $(".menu-over").animate({
    left: "-50%",
    }, 1000 );

    $( ".mainsite" ).animate({
    left: "0%",
    width:"100%" ,
    }, 1000 );

  } else {// even clicks

    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-bars fa-times');
    $(this).toggleClass('cross');
    $('.menu-over ul li').toggleClass('animated-fast slideInLeft')

    $(".menu-over").animate({
    left: "0%",
    }, 1000 );

    $( ".mainsite" ).animate({
    left: "50%",
    width:"50%" ,
    }, 1000 );

  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
});
```

Comment: Is your click element an `<a>`? Check `preventDefault()`

Comment: Use javascript:void(0) in href of a to avoid any action

Answer (score 0):

Try to `return false` at the end of the function. Greetings

Comment: Thanks for these, unfortunately it still jumps to the top. I think its something to do with the odd/even clicks functions that is causing it but can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

You should have `.preventDefault()` inside your click event:

```
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
```

or you can use `return false;` which should work the same way in your case:

```
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function(event) {
         return false;
```

Comment: Thanks for these, unfortunately neither work. I think its something to do with the odd/even clicks functions that is causing it but can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Thanks for all the suggestions but strangely none of them worked. It was the animation of width on .mainsite that was causing it. Changed it to a padding effect instead and now all stays put when clicked.